# CollectionType form expecting wrong type entity

Tags: symfony

I'm trying render a form of all cyties (well "ville") and postal codes in my database, so that the user can either edit anything or add a new city. I'm doing that with a CollectionType so i can have just one big form (as per [documentations](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.htm).

Here is my CitiesCollectionType :

```
use App\Entity\Ville;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;


class VillesCollectionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('villes',CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type'=> VilleType::class,
                'entry_options'=>['label'=>false],
                'allow_add'=>true,
            ])


        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Ville::class,

        ]);
    }
```

and my VilleType

```
use App\Entity\Ville;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class VilleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nom')
            ->add('codePostal')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Ville::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I'm loading all my cities from my database in my controller with findAll(), and i get an array of cities.
Here's the error i get :

> The form's view data is expected to be a "App\Entity\Ville", but it is a "array". You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms "array" to an instance of "App\Entity\Ville".

I'm understanding my form should expect an array of "ville", and i can't understand why it expects a single entity.

Answer (score 0):

In your first snippet you have the wrong class

```
$resolver->setDefaults([
   'data_class' => Ville::class,
]);
```

here you have to set the collection class